# Adding UITextField to Custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am wanting to create a form style TableView with a label on the left of the cell and TextField on the right.

However, I am having a difficult time finding information on TextField's inside custom TableViewCells. Is it even possible? I thought perhaps a xib file, but not much luck on finding answers there either.

Greatly appreciate some guidance.

```
 import UIKit

class AddProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,
UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    let sectionTitles: [String] = ["PROFILES", "IDENTIFICATION", "EMERGENCY CONTACTS"]
    let sectionImages: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow")]

    let s1Data: [String] = ["Barn Name", "Show Name", "Color", "Gender", "Breed", "Birth Date", "Heigh (Hh)"]
    let s2Data: [String] = ["Markings", "Tattoo", "Branding", "Microchip ID", "Passport", "Registration", "Registration #"]
    let s3Data: [String] = ["Contact Name", "Contact Phone", "Vet Name", "Vet Phone", "Farrier Name", "Farrier Phone"]


    var sectionData: [Int: [String]] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

        sectionData = [0:s1Data, 1:s2Data, 2:s3Data]

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
        -> Int {
            return (sectionData[section]?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = sectionTitles[section]
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 5, width: 200, height: 35)
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 15)
        label.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        view.addSubview(label)

        let image = UIImageView(image: sectionImages[section])
        image.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 8, width: 25, height: 25)
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(image)

        return view

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionTitles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

            if cell == nil {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell");
            }


            cell!.textLabel?.text = sectionData[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]
            cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 13)
            cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

            return cell!

    }


}
```

Comment: Do you use storyboards?

Comment: I haven't with this, but I can do. I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: I think this tutorial will help you: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/02/12/custom-uitableviewcell-text-input-swift/

Comment: Thank you @user1000 Despite a few errors, this link was most helpful. Appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible. Try following this steps:

1. Add your UILabel and UITextField to your UITableViewCell (you can use NIB or Storyboard)
2. Make your TableViewController conform to UITextFieldDelegate
3. When you dequeue your cell, set your textfield’s delegate to your TableViewController
4. In didSelectRow make your textField become firstResponder (so you don’t have to tap precisely on the textField)

Don’t have a computer here to test, but let me know if this helps

Answer (score -3):

Use protocols to finding the info and use stroyboard for creating layouts

Hope it will help!.